# what does the comma represent listing files in linux?

Tags: unix, ls

When I run

```
ls -l
```

I see a comma among the list of files. Do you know what is that? and how can I remove that?

Comment: do you have a file named `,`?

Comment: No, there should not be any file named ','. Do you know why it gets generated?. I was trying to move files from that directory to its child directory

Comment: I know. But is it possible you mistakenly created it when you were moving files? Because `,` is a valid filename.

Comment: Paste `ls -l` output to clarify what you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

The character `,` has no particular meaning while listing files so the root cause looks to be you simply have a file named that way.

`rm ,` would then be the more sensible way to remove it.